# Efficiently way to read binary files in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to read a binary file (16 MB) in which I have only integers coded on 16 bits. So for that, I used chunks of 1 MB which gives me an array of bytes. For my own needs, I convert this byte array to a short array with the following function convert but reading this file with a buffer and convert it into a short array take me 5 seconds, is it a faster way than my solution ?

```
 def convert(in: Array[Byte]): Array[Short] = in.grouped(2).map {
    case Array(one) => (one << 8 | (0 toByte)).toShort
    case Array(hi, lo) => (hi << 8 | lo).toShort
  } .toArray

  val startTime = System.nanoTime()

val file = new RandomAccessFile("foo","r")
val defaultBlockSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024
    val byteBuffer = new Array[Byte](defaultBlockSize)
    val chunkNums = (file.length / defaultBlockSize).toInt
    for (i <- 1 to chunkNums) {
      val seek = (i - 1) * defaultBlockSize
      file.seek(seek)
      file.read(byteBuffer)
      val s = convert(byteBuffer)
      println(byteBuffer size)
    }

val stopTime = System.nanoTime()
  println("Perf of = " + ((stopTime - startTime) / 1000000000.0) + " for a duration of " + duration + " s")
```

Comment: Er, in what decade is 16 MB "huge"?  The JVM overhead is usually 10x that or more.

Comment: Maybe it's because it's the first time that I read such files but I removed the "huge".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

16 MB easily fits in memory unless you're running this on a feature phone or something.  No need to chunk it and make the logic harder.

Just gulp the whole file at once with `java.nio.files.Files.readAllBytes`:

```
val buffer = java.nio.files.Files.readAllBytes(myfile.toPath)
```

assuming you are not stuck with Java 1.6.  (If you are stuck with Java 1.6, pre-allocate your buffer size using `myfile.size`, and use `read` on a `FileInputStream` to get it all in one go.  It's not much harder, just don't forget to close it!)

Then if you don't want to convert it yourself, you can

```
val bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer)
bb.order(java.nio.ByteOrder.nativeOrder)
val shorts = new Array[Short](buffer.length/2)
bb.asShortBuffer.get(shorts)
```

And you're done.

Note that this is all Java stuff; there's nothing Scala-specific here save the syntax.

<sup>If you're wondering why this is *so* much faster than your code, it's because `grouped(2)` boxes the bytes and places them in an array.  That's *three* allocations for every short you want!  You can do it yourself by indexing the array directly, and that will be fast, but why would you want to when `ByteBuffer` and friends do exactly what you need already?</sup>

<sup>If you really *really* care about that last (odd) byte, then you can use `(buffer.length + 1)/2` for the size of `shorts`, and tack on a `if ((buffer.length) & 1 == 1) shorts(shorts.length-1) = ((bb.get&0xFF) << 8).toShort` to grab the last byte.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and also for the last byte. I need to get all the values from the file and so the last (odd) byte is also important to me :)

Comment: @alifirat - It's a very strange encoding scheme where you leave off the last byte of a short when writing it to disk!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues pop out:

If `byteBuffer` is always going to be 1024*1024 size then the `case Array(one)` in `convert` will never actually be used and therefore pattern matching is unnecessary.

Also, you can avoid the for loop with a tail recursive function.  After the `val byteBuffer = ...` line you can replace the chunkNums and for loop with:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def readAndConvert(b: List[Array[Short]], file : RandomAccessFile) : List[Array[Short]] = {
  if(file.read(byteBuffer) < 0)
    b
  else {
    file.skipBytes(1024*1024)
    readAndConvert(b.+:(convert(byteBuffer)), file)
  }
}

val sValues = readAndConvert(List.empty[Array[Short]], file)
```

Note: because list preppending is much faster than appending the above loop gets you the converted value in reverse order from the reading order in the file.

Comment: None of these are the real issue.

Comment: I disagree, seek is much more expensive than skip and the for loop used in the question is not optimized.